# Having trouble setting two different rates for traffic light

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a traffic light program that has two different rates depending on what the user wants (a fast and a slow). However, I'm having trouble compiling due to this error on both of my buttons:

> error CS0123: A method or delegate `TrafficLight.signal(object, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)` parameters do not match delegate `System.EventHandler(object, System.EventArgs)` parameters.

For reference here is some of the code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;

public class TrafficLight : Form {
    private RadioButton fast = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
    private RadioButton slow = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
    private GroupBox rateOfChange = new GroupBox();
    private static System.Timers.Timer Tclock = new System.Timers.Timer();
    private ulong tickCounter = 0;
}

public TrafficLight() {
    Tclock.Enabled = false;
    Tclock.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(signal);
    Tclock.Interval = 1000;
    //error occurs on these next two.
    fast.Click += signal;
    slow.Click += signal;

}

//same error marked here.
protected void signal(System.Object send, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    if(send == fast) {
    tickCounter++;
    switch(Light) {
      case trafficColor.red:
      if(tickCounter > 4) {
        tickCounter = 0;
        Light = trafficColor.green;
        Invalidate();
      }
      break;
      case trafficColor.yellow:
      if(tickCounter > 1) {
        tickCounter = 0;
        Light = trafficColor.red;
        Invalidate();
      }
      break;
      case trafficColor.green:
      if(tickCounter > 3) {
        tickCounter = 0;
        Light = trafficColor.yellow;
        Invalidate();
      }
      break;
    }
    else if(send == slow) {
    tickCounter++;
    switch(Light) {
      case trafficColor.red:
      if(tickCounter > 8) {
        tickCounter = 0;
        Light = trafficColor.green;
        Invalidate();
      }
      break;
      case trafficColor.yellow:
      if(tickCounter > 2) {
        tickCounter = 0;
        Light = trafficColor.red;
        Invalidate();
      }
      break;
    case trafficColor.green:
      if(tickCounter > 6) {
        tickCounter = 0;
        Light = trafficColor.yellow;
        Invalidate();
      }
      break;
}
```

Comment: I didn't look at your code too closely, but to fix the error you quoted, you just change the type of the second parameter of `signal` to `EventArgs` instead.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the code lines `slow.Click += signal;`? It's a button click event, which obviously isn't an `ElapsedEventHandler`.

Comment: You seem to want to be able to click on a button and have the same event handler execute as is when the timer elapses. Your event handler does not appear to ever actually use the `e` parameter. So, it doesn't actually need to be of type `ElapsedEventArgs`. You should be able to get your code working by changing the method declaration to `protected void signal(System.Object send, EventArgs e)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the lines causing the error, you are attempting to use an event handler that requires an `ElapsedEventArgs` object to be passed as the second parameter. But, the `Click` event can only provide an `EventArgs` object. It wouldn't even have the slightest idea of where to get a timer-related event args object when a mouse-click event happens.

On the other hand, your event handler never actually uses the event args object passed to it. And `ElapsedEventArgs` is a subclass of `EventArgs`. So, it *is* legal for you to change the event handler declaration to `protected void signal(System.Object send, EventArgs e)` and use that same event handler for both the `Timer.Elapsed` event and the `Click` event.

This works because an event handler with that signature can accept *any* `EventArgs` object passed to it as the second argument. That can either be a plain old `EventArgs` object, as will be provided by the `Click` event. Or it can be the `ElapsedEventArgs` object provided by the `Elapsed` event. Since `ElapsedEventArgs` inherits `EventArgs`, it also "is a" `EventArgs` object and satisfies the parameter's type requirement as well.

(None of the above should be considered endorsement of the design of having the same event handler respond to both timer-elapsed events and mouse-click events :) )